# Слетает кодировка после обновления блока

Tags: jquery, ajax, кодировка, обновление, javascript

Всем привет. У меня есть скрипт, который автоматически обновляет блок.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
setInterval("jQuery('#timeA').load('# dl#timeB');",5000);
});
</script>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что после обновления блока, кириллический текст превращается в
`����� ����`
такую фигню.
Кодировка страниц `cp1251`.
Я в JS/Jquery/Ajax дуб-дерево. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться...
Или, в принципе, можно другйо скрипт обновления. Главное, чтоб скрипт обновлял блок, а грузил информацию с другого файла.

Comment: AddDefaultCharset помог, спасибо.

Comment: @Morty, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).@Morty, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советовал бы отдавать контенет в utf-8 или соаоставить кодировки на сервере. Есть конечно еще функция ajaxSetup в которой можно выставить кодировку. Но все-таки сопоставьте кодировки файла и стандартной кодировки из htaccess
.htaccess
AddDefaultCharset WINDOWS-1251

Должно помочь если у вас все в cp1251